# Twitter Bootstrap remove table row highlight with row stripes

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a simple way to remove the tr:hover style from twitter bootstrap such that I can still use their table styling without getting the row highlight on hover?

Comment: Does your table use the bootstrap "table-striped" class? If yes, please review the jsfiddles I've added below to see what happens if you don't account for the "table-striped" class.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

@Blender's answer is right on, but only if you are **not** using the `.table-striped` class on your table.

If you **are** using the `.table-striped` class, the row highlight will not go away when you hover over a row that has the light-grey colored stripe.

What will happen when you hover over the light-grey row is that the row will change from light-grey to transparent (white), and thus you will be inadvertently implementing a row-hover effect on all the light-grey colored rows.

If you need to take away the hover effect from the striped rows as well, then building upon Blender's original answer, I think you would have another rule to over-ride:

```css
.table tbody tr:hover td,
.table tbody tr:hover th {
  background-color: transparent;
}


.table-striped tbody tr:nth-child(odd):hover td {
   background-color: #F9F9F9;
}
```

**good example**: Here's a link to a working jsfiddle example where the .table-striped class is accounted for: 
http://jsfiddle.net/pXWjq/

**buggy example**: And here's an example where the table row hover still happens (on the grey rows) because the grey-row hover is not accounted for: 
http://jsfiddle.net/448Rb/

​

Comment: That's awesome, but you forgot the additional odd hover state for the second block: `.table-striped tbody tr:nth-child(odd):hover th`

Answer (score 16):

Override these rules:

```
.table tbody tr:hover td,
.table tbody tr:hover th {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

Using this:

```
.table tbody tr:hover td,
.table tbody tr:hover th {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```