# Twitter bootstrap take out the hover background color on tables

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've spent 45min looking on how to remove the background color change on row hover.

See Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BJrnC/1/

Just in case I'm not clear. When you hover a row in the tbody of a table using bootstrap, the background goes to grey. The problem is that I really like the layout they have, but I just don't like that.

How can I disable it?

Thanks.

Comment: The answer you accepted will work, so long as you don't include the css class of .table-striped.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763166/twitter-bootstrap-remove-table-row-highlight-with-row-stripes/10763397#10763397

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can add the following on your stylesheet to overwrite that feature:

```
.table tbody tr:hover td, .table tbody tr:hover th {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BJrnC/2/

---

**Note**: Noticed that I'm still getting upvoted for this answer. The twitter bootstrap now does this by default. If you want to add hover effects to a table simply add the `.table-hover` hover class to the body of your table, otherwise just omit it and it should not have any effects when hovered. This only applies to the latest version of the bootstrap.

Comment: Upvoted because I needed to change the hover color (via CSS) when I had another class on the row.

Comment: I don't get it, I used this and it worked when i wanted a different color when a row had a custom class added to it, and today it stopped working for a reason that I cannot figure out at all, I don;t think I even changed anything.