# Twitter bootstrap remove tr hover?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there any simple way to remove tr hover for certain tr, not for all ? 
I saw [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11044046/twitter-bootstrap-take-out-the-hover-background-color-on-tables) but its working for all table rows.

Thank you !

Comment: can you make a fiddle to illustrate the question with a example? also, have you tried anything besides the linked answer?

Comment: Then target the *certain* row? `.certain-row:hover`, `#certain-row:hover`, ...

Comment: Certain tr as in by class or id or name or value or colour?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/s7yc91v6/ 
For example i dont want to change background-color on hover for table row Mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by adding a class to the rows you don't want to have the hover background colour apply to.

```
.table-hover>tbody>tr.anti-hover:hover>td,
.table-hover>tbody>tr.anti-hover:hover>th {
  background: white;
}
```

And your table would look like this:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
  <tr class="">
    <td>This</td>
    <td>has</td>
    <td>hover</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="anti-hover">
    <td>No</td>
    <td>hover</td>
    <td>here</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Example Bootply [here](http://www.bootply.com/lsrFYcVlpH).