# Add highlight on clickable table row (using bootstrap) - CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to highlight row on mouseover (hover). I am using bootstrap and on the table I use their class `table-striped` , so when I write css:

```
tbody {
  tr:hover {
    background-color: #ff0;
  }
}
```

It only changes color on rows that are white, but not the other ones.
Not sure what the best way to solve this problem is. Maybe I can overwrite table-striped highlighting somehow? How would I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using the 'table-hover' and override the color like this..

```
.table-hover>tbody>tr:hover>td, .table-hover>tbody>tr:hover>th {
  background-color: #550055;
  color:#eeeeee;
}
```

http://bootply.com/93988

Comment: Just found an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763166/twitter-bootstrap-remove-table-row-highlight-with-row-stripes . Was gonna delete the question but it's too late! Anyway thanks for the help.